# Parallel Operating System (How to virtualize a second OS)?

Tags: macos, virtualization

Can anyone tell me how to install two operating system on one PC such that both operating systems can be used at the same time?

Comment: I smell hackintosh here. Are you trying to run both windows and osx in your PC?

Comment: no basically i went through an article regarding this, but couldnt get much idea. so lukd for sum further help

Comment: so you are saying how to run two PC OS together, right? I notice you have the OSX tag, that's why I thought you want to talk about hackintosh.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) to do this, and allow it to operate in seamless mode.

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is a nice **cross-platform**, *free* application which allows you to do this.  You can emulate nearly every operating system under one-another.  The full list of compatible guest operating systems can be found [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes).

The following is Mac OS X emulating Windows XP in seamless mode:

[image: VirtualBox Seamless Mode Example]

And the following is Mac OS X again, but emulating Mandriva Linux:

[image: VirtualBox Seamless Mode Example]

While you can use seamless mode, I find it much easier to just switch between them using Fullscreen mode... Although this depends largely on the purpose of the virtual machine.

Comment: And VirtualBox is free, too.

Comment: If you don't mind paying, or want support (but don't expect much support from Parallels - their support sucks), the commercial alternatives are: <a href="http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/">VMWare</a> (more stable and dependable), and <a href="http://www.parallels.com/">Parallels Desktop</a> (very fast and tons of features, but more fragile and terrible support).

Comment: Sorry - assumed we could use HTML in comments:
http://www.parallels.com/
http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/

Comment: can i run windows xp and windows 2003 with the help of this application

Comment: Yes you can.  You can install either OS first, then emulate the other one by installing it into a virtual machine.  Then start up the virtual machine, and set it to "Seamless Mode".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use use two Operating systems at the exact same time without some virtual environment (e.g. a [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor)).

You can install two and use them independently of each other, however.
For example, you can do a clean install of Windows XP and partition your hard drive into two partitions during the install.  The Install Windows Vista or Windows 7 or some flavor of Linux to the second partition.  This will allow you to choose which OS to start during each boot.